CSS background image does not appear
I have CSS-styled span element with a width and height, and a background-image, which does not appear although a box of the expected size is reserved on-screen.
If I try a different jpg file, the other image then appears successfully. The ‘bad’ image is in the same directory as the .css file, and the same place as the good .jpg. I’ve tried using an online jpg.repair tool in case the file was somehow corrupted, but to no avail.
I have also tried converting the .jpg to a png, remembering to change the file name appropriately in the CSS, luckily. Again no help. Since other images display fine, I’m assuming that it is something to do with the particular file, but the .png didn’t display either.
I’ve tried renaming the file, changing the CSS accordingly, just in case some bug means that the browser (Safari iPadOS) doesn’t like the file name. Desperation unrewarded. The CSS is not somehow bad because the other images do display.
The CSS is roughly: background: url("buidheag-in-grass-small.jpg") no-repeat top center; - iirc. The image file is referenced in a separate .css file, not inline in the xhtml. I’m using Safari on an iPad with iPadOS 17.x. The web server engine is Apache/linux. Apache is explicitly set up to serve the correct mime type for .jpg files.
I’m absolutely stumped. I’ve read various other posts, nearly all of which are concerned with problems with incorrect file paths. I only have one directory for all files, so no /img/ or /css/ subdirectories.
Hope someone can help me.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I’m not asking for help with the code, but for ideas about why one particular image might not display, when other ones do.

I can’t use the snippet editor on an iPad because it shows an error saying it can’t run on an iPad or similar.

can you open this file with software like Gimp?

I’ve tried opening the jpg file with other tools on the ipad and I’ve converted it to a .png file, no joy, it displays fine elsewhere. I haven’t yet tried gimp. I can download it on my wife’s M2 Mac perhaps?

You can see the xhtml and css at "https:// ssh-test . me /" - remove the spaces, inserted so web crawlers won’t find and list the test website.

Note that the file is not html but xhtml5, and is served as such. The relevant CSS block is referenced by #id. Search the CSS in welcome.css for buidheag if you get lost.

sounds obvious, but double-check the spelling of the filename

I and my wife both have double-checked the spelling of the filename and have copy-pasted it from the Files app into the CSS just in case of utter madness. The files are on the www for all to inspect. There’s no initial forward-slash in the CSS and no path name.

We have also checked that we have uploaded the CSS and the xhtml, and have cleared the browser caches on both my Safari and my wife’s.

I have just run the W3C CSS validator ‘jigsaw’ on the file welcome.css, with no errors (note TLS ie https:). I validated everything early this morning, all xhtml and all CSS.

I found it. The file does not exist on the server, hence the 403. This is because it never got uploaded! Unbelievably stupid. Thanks to Akshay Kumar.

It is now uploaded, and so the problem is fixed.
